# problem with catkin_make, rospack find package but not catkin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I tried to building a node (chapter2_tutorials) but I can't build the package

I created a workspace at home/user/ros_workspace
I put the package in this folder --> chapter2_tutorials.
When I try to find this package with rospack find chapter2_tutorials, it is ok.

But when I try to execture catkin_make --pkg chapter2_tutorials I have:
Packages "chapter2_tutorials" not found in the workspace.

For information, I put at the end of bashrc
source /home/user/ros_workspace/catkin/devel/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~ros_workspace:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262777/problem-with-catkin_make,-rospack-find-package-but-not-catkin/) by [anthoSoben](https://answers.ros.org/users/30552/anthosoben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-05-29**:
Don't mess with `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` manually. I would remove the `export` line from your `.bashrc`. Also, it's `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` that you should be sourcing first and foremost. Is that in your `.bashrc` ?

**Comment by [anthoSoben](https://answers.ros.org/users/30552/anthosoben/) on 2017-05-30**:
Hi,
Thanks to help me.
But if I remove the export line, ROS don't find my package in my personnal workspace (ros_workspace) when I execute "rospack find chapter2_tutorials"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[chapter2_tutorials](https://github.com/AaronMR/Learning_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming/tree/master/chapter2_tutorials) is a `rosbuild` package so you need to use `rosmake` tool: `rosmake chapter2_tutorials`

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2017-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0